# Constant current LED driver replacement

Tags: led, constant-current

I have a LED lamp fixture with a constant current driver that I need to replace. The old driver has a set of DIP switches to select the output current and is currently set to 29W and 650mA constant with voltage range of 3..44 V (DC) and U out of 55 V.

The exact same replacement driver is no longer available. The lamp fixture is enclosed so I have no idea about the number of LEDs inside or what type they are. The closest match I could find from the same manufacturer is a model with similar DIP switches, but I'd have the following settings to choose from:

| P out W | V out DC | V out DC | U out V |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27 | 10...54 | 500 mA const. | 59 |
| 29,5 | 10...54 | 550 mA const. | 59 |
| 32 | 10...54 | 600 mA const. | 59 |
| 35 | 10...54 | 650 mA const. | 59 |

Which settings should I choose to match my old drivers' 29W/650mA/3..44V & most importantly - **why?**

Comment: `voltage range of 3..44 V (DC) and U out of 55 V` so 3..44 V is input? What's that with the prospective replacement, and what is the power source past&future?

Comment: 3..44 V (DC) is the output voltage range. Input voltage is 220-230V.

Comment: `3..44 V (DC) is the output voltage range` Ah. Can't see how `and U out of 55 V` fits this.

Comment: Neither do I, but that's exactly what's printed on the driver. "V out DC" with that range and "U out V" with a value of 55.

Comment: 55v is the open circuit voltage.

Answer (score 1):

It's a constant current driver, so the current is the important parameter. The voltage will adjust itself as necessary to maintain the correct current, and the power is a maximum rating.

Based on the numbers of 29W and 650mA, the voltage for your particular lamp is about 45V - about the maximum voltage of the old driver. Even though the new driver can go higher, that would make the current higher than 650mA so it won't.

Comment: If I set my new driver to the same 650mA, doesn't the wattage also have a chance of going from 29 watts to 35 watts? What keeps that one down?

Comment: @allu The LED always has the same voltage at the same current. To increase the voltage the driver would have to increase the current as well, which it doesn't want to do. Watts = volts times amps

Comment: @allu Because this is a constant current driver, it's designed to keep the same current no matter what - it doesn't care what the voltage is (as long as it's not too high or too low) and it doesn't care what the power(watts) is (as long as it's not too high, overloading the driver)